# Trouble solving this limit without using l'Hôpital's rule

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

The limit I want to calculate is the following
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{(e^{\sin(4x)}-1)}{\ln\big(1+\tan(2x)\big)}}
$$
I've been stuck on this limit for a while and I don't know how to solve it please help me.

Comment: You'd have more trouble doing this **with** the Hospital's rule. The differentiations are awfully tedious.

Comment: One general strategy is to write out the first few term of the Taylor series expansions of the ingredients and do the algebra to find the first few terms of the series for the full expression. (Not posted as an answer because I haven't tried it.)

Answer (score 10):

Hint: $$\frac{(e^{\sin 4x}-1)}{\ln(1+\tan 2x)}= \frac{(e^{\sin 4x}-1)}{\sin 4x}\frac{\tan 2x}{\ln(1+ \tan 2x)} \frac{\sin 4x}{4x}  \frac{2x}{\tan 2x} \times 2.$$

Comment: hey thank you for the hint , so does this limit = 2?

Comment: @Levio, Yeah, your right.

Comment: The omitted signs between fraction confused me for a second. I'd better get some sleep.

Answer (score 3):

As $x\to 0$,
$$\exp(\sin 4x)-1\sim\sin4x\sim 4x$$
and
$$\ln(1+\tan 2x)\sim\tan2x\sim 2x$$
etc.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Make use the following  facts:
1.  $\dfrac{e^{\sin(4x)} -  1}{\sin(4x)} \to 1$

2.$\dfrac{\log(1 + \tan(2x))}{\tan(2x)}  \to  1$

3. $\cos(2x) \to 1$

Comment: thanks for the hints I managed to solve it